# GRUB2 under Mint: Booting PC-BSD without chainloading?

Tags: grub2, bsd

Wanting to try several operating-systems, I installed the following on a MBR-partitioned harddrive:

Partition 1: FreeBSD on UFS split in root-slice and swap.

No problem booting...

Partition 2: PC-BSD on UFS split in root-slice, swap, var and usr

Got a menu allowing me to choose between the two, no problem booting either...

Partition 5: (logical 1): LinuxMint root-partition (using other logical partitions for swap etc.)

Installed GRUB2, no problem booting LinuxMint, but no way to select other OS'.

In /etc/grub.d I then added the following entries:

15_freebsd:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo "Adding FreeBSD..."
cat << EOF
menuentry "FreeBSD" {
   set root=(hd0,1)
   chainloader (hd0,1)+1
   }
EOF
```

16_pcbsd:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo "Adding PC-BSD..."
cat << EOF
menuentry "PC-BSD" {
   set root=(hd0,2)
   chainloader (hd0,2)+1
   }
EOF
```

I set them both to executable, ran `grub2-update` and `grub-install /dev/sda`.

I now had entries for both FreeBSD and PC-BSD.  Using the one for FreeBSD worked as expected, I booted into FreeBSD...  But using the one for PC-BSD, *also* booted into FreeBSD - *not* PC-BSD as I'd expected.

I can't frankly see what I did wrong, so `chainloading` obviously doesn't work for my set-up.  I was therefor wondering what the correct parameters to boot PC-BSD directly (ie. without chainloading) from GRUB installed under LinuxMint?  The weirdest part is of course that the PC-BSD entry "worked" - it just booted the wrong OS...

(Of course, any ideas on why chainloading worked with FreeBSD but not PC-BSD would also be a help.)

Comment: Your grub setup seems to be correct. Inside Linux, what is the result of a `fdisk -l`. Could you post it here?

Comment: I pasted the result here: http://pastebin.com/038yc5K3   I did fool around a bit, and by changing the boot-flag from FreeBSD to PC-BSD, PC-BSD booted instead.  However, boot-flag for both, for another OS (Solaris) or for non at all (no boot-flag at all); all caused FreeBSD to boot.  Obviously I need an alternative to chainloader.

Comment: I was a bit unclear: "by changing the boot-flag from FreeBSD to PC-BSD, PC-BSD booted instead."  Unfortunately, it was now PC-BSD which was booted for both the FreeBSD and PC-BSD menu-choice (instead of FreeBSD for both).

Comment: So, Looking at your configuration, it seems that the setroot is ok(since partitions now start with 1 on grub2...what a mess). What about if you use the ufs2 module taking a different way as explained here: - http://slackwiki.com/Dual_Booting_With_FreeBSD_9 - The root entries of each OS remains the same, for sure ;)